# What Does this Page speed result mean?

Tags: pagespeed

I ran my homepage through the PageSpeed Insights tool on Google. Under Field Data and Origin Summary I see that it says 
"The Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this page." What does this mean?

I checked with my website company and they told me 'Several of the metrics are off – such as when they load an incognito window (meaning the home page isn’t cached on my browser) it does not take as long to load as Google Pagespeed indicates.'

How accurate are Google's page speed results?